# how to make Firefox menu more readable while keeping dark theme?

Tags: gnome, firefox, gui, 17.10, gnome-tweak-tool

How can I configure Firefox menus so that, while it keeps the dark theme, the menu -- specifically the bookmarks -- are easier to navigate?

[image: bookmarks]

It's hard to pick out where one sub-menu merges into another...

My gnome tweak tools settings:

[image: tweak]

On `artful`, 17.10 version -- using GNOME and not Unity.

Comment: If you want a dark theme you may try something else from gnome-look.org or from other sources. I would recommend Arc-Dark theme.

Comment: So you want the sub-menu's background to be visibly distinguishable from the primary menu's background? In your image, it's easy enough to tell what's a sub-menu even without much difference in background color.